# "xrandr: Configuration crtc 0 failed" after xrandr --addmode command

Tags: display, display-resolution, xrandr

My aspect ratio is annoying and not normal, so I did the following commands:

```
cvt 1280 720
xrandr --newmode "1280x720_60.00 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode default 1280x720_60.00
xrandr --output default --mode 1280x720_60.00
```

To which I get the following comand:

xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed

After some internet searching, I then wrote

```
xrandr --output default --mode 1280x720_60.00 --brightness 0.7 --gamma 0.3:0.3:0.3
```

But now I get:

```
Gamma Size is 0
```

I then went on to Arandr, and the resolution I set is there, but when I try to switch it, it will glitch the screen for a split second then say "Configure crtc 0 failed".

Any help would be appreciated, but apologies for any grammatical errors, English is not my first language.

This is what I get from --verbose:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (0x399) normal (normal) 0mm x 
0mm
Identifier: 0x398
Timestamp:  83296
Subpixel:   unknown
Clones:    
CRTC:       0
CRTCs:      0
Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
           filter: 
_MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
non-desktop: 0 
    supported: 0, 1
```

1024x768 (0x399) 59.769MHz *current
h: width  1024 start    0 end    0 total 1024 skew    0 clock  58.37KHz
v: height  768 start    0 end    0 total  768           clock  76.00Hz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have multiple output devices? You will probably need to specify the `crtc` number when setting the resolution.

First get your `crtc` number with:

```
xrandr --verbose
```

Now make this part of the command:

```
xrandr --output CRT1 --crtc CRT1 --mode 1280x720_60.00 --brightness 0.7 --gamma 0.3:0.3:0.3
```

Remember to change `CRT1` to the value you receive from the `--verbose` output.

That should do it.

Comment: I have one output device which is my monitor (running on VGA). and when I do "xrandr --verbose" I get the output that is written on the original question. Which part of that is the value I should replace the CRT1 with? Thanks